# What can I do that a SQL Server attached file can not delete from computer?

Tags: sql-server-express

I have attached a database file to SQL Server Express using below TSQL command

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [example] ON 
( FILENAME = N'F:\example.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'F:\example.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH ;
GO
```

After database attached successfully, the source file of database `example.mdf` and `example.ldf` simplicity can be delete and this a security threat, what can I do that This file cannot delete from computer

Comment: Do not rely on DBMS locking access to its files. When DBMS is shut down it does not protect data from being deleted. Protect database files by restricting access to directories in which database files are located.

Comment: Lock the door of the server room and stick a sign on it that says "Dangerous High Voltages Inside".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the SQL side, nothing. The only thing you can do is restrict administrative access to the computer itself and set proper file permissions on the directory and files that the database resides in.

If a Administrator user wants to delete your file there is nothing you, as a programmer, can do about it.